# Maximum input capacitance of IO-Link-Device on C/Q

Tags: capacitance, input

I have a bit of trouble understanding the IO-Link-specification concerning the input capacitance of the C/Q-pin.

The specification says in [table 7 (line 754)](http://www.io-link.com/share/Downloads/Spec-Interface/IOL-Interface-Spec_10002_V112_Jul13.pdf#page=46):

> CQD Input capacitance min: 0  max: 1,0 nF, Effective capacitance
>   between C/Q and L+ or L- of Device in receive state

Do I have to interpret it this way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb5kH5m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or this way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f025lem.png)</sup>

This might be a rather stupid question but `or` for me is ambiguous in this case (like [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95624/use-of-or-inclusive-or-exclusive)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some questions around knowledgeable people, the conclusion was that the total capacity is relevant and we better stick to the sum being smaller than 1,0 nF.